# How should inter-related software packages be versioned?

Tags: release, semantic-versioning

Some open-source projects make combined releases where the version number of each package(library) is increased to the same version.

Examples in Java are:

- org.springframework
- com.fasterxml.jackson
- org.hamcrest

This implies that some packages may get a new version even though they have not changed (nor their dependencies). I don't think this violates semantic versioning.

Benefits I see is that:

- Users can use a single version to monitor and upgrade
- All users likely to use the same combination of libraries

Drawbacks:

- Users using just one out of many libraries might be notified about an "update" though the package to download has not changed
- If many users use just a sub-package, then all bug reports for one version are equally for a range of versions, which is difficult to track. Reverting to the previous "different" version to avoid a bug becomes more complex.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38496022, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45417741

Answer (score 0):

One alternative to single-versioning is to use a BOM (Bill-of-materials). 
Different concepts of BOMs exist:

- A BOM can list several dependencies to include in their versions (e.g. [Linux apt Meta-packages](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/59088/what-is-the-formal-definition-of-a-meta-package))
- A BOM can define versions (and other restrictions) for dependencies to be used if the dependency is included (e.g. Java Maven [`dependencyManagement`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619598/differences-between-dependencymanagement-and-dependencies-in-maven) section of BOM)

The BOM allows to declare which configuration(combination) of library-versions have been tested together, and allows separate groups of users to all use the same configuration, helping with bug reports and reproducibility.

Not all software distribution and buildsystems support the BOM concept equally well, though.

Comment: In some places this is called a virtual package. It has no contents, only dependencies.

Comment: Most of the Linux distribution package managers, use virtual packages to install groups of packages. I don't have a specific reference.

Comment: I added meta-packages to my answer with a link. The only explanation I found for virtual packages is for Debian: https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html#s-virtual, but it seems that is a different concept solving a different problem.