# install package globally in Net 5.0

Tags: c#

How install packages in Net 5.0 runtime of local (or remote) computer, so that will be available for all projects I create, **without add explicitly to each project with nuget** ?

Ideally each package installed in this way should be reachable just declaring it's namespace.
Example:

- the package is Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
- install this way the package
- create a console .net application, and I **do not** add nuget package
- use package classes just declaring "using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration"

Hope there is a way to do this

Comment: Why not create [own template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/custom-templates)?

Comment: I don't think such a feature exists, and that's a good thing: It would make .NET projects non-portable, since they could depend on packages which are only locally available. That portability is actually one of the big *advantages* of nuget (as opposed to just referencing DLLs of locally installed libraries, like you did in the dark, old days).

Comment: The entire point of a csproj file is to tell the build system how to compile your code and what dependencies are needed. Lets say you commit the code to source control and someone else downloads it, their system will no longer know what references are required.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done. It would quite quickly become unusable when different projects needs different versions of these packages (like when you start a new .Net 6 project in the future and all old projects want the .Net 5 assemblies).

What you could do however is to create your own meta package with your default list of packages, that way you would only need to install one package to your new projects which would then include all the ones you want.

[How to create meta package (package of all packages) like Microsoft.AspNetCore.All in nuget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45417741/how-to-create-meta-package-package-of-all-packages-like-microsoft-aspnetcore-a)